# why data is not getting from database to table?

Tags: angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

My controller Code is:

```
$scope.getRegistration=function(){
    $http.get('/api').success(function(data) {       
        $scope.registration=data;
    }).error(function(status) {
        console.log('Error: ' + status);
    });    
};
```

why data is not getting from database to table?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I think you need to give us more information about your environment/setup